# CSS copyright issue?

Tags: css

There are plenty of websites that inspires me. If I like design or their css or javascript, can I copy it to my local folder and use it?

To give you an example, if I find a site xyz.com and liked their login screen. Can I copy their css, background images (plain gradient ones) and create my own version with little modification?

Comment: How do you mean "Can I copy ..."?  Are you able to do it?  Probably.  Do you have a *legal* right to do it?  That's a question for you to ask the other site and/or an attorney.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  If you want legal advice, ask a lawyer.

Comment: If you want to take legal advice from random people with no legal education, but who do listen to rumors now and then, at least tell us where you live.  While the base issues of copyright are much the same across the world, the details are not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS code is not copyrightable by itself insofar as the markup goes.

However, owners can finagle their CSS implementation into something called **trade dress**, which is fancy-talk for how a company distinguishes itself from other competing companies.

To summarise a very long, long argument:  copyright can be applied to the distinguishing design of a website. However, the markup as an entity cannot be by itself copyrighted.

Because HTML / CSS is not **machine code** (its *markup* or *script*), copyright laws can only be loosely applied to it.

Once you bring *efficiency* and *algorithmic programming* into the argument, those can be copyrighted in the United States. Therefore, if you, somehow, program a "special" algorithm into CSS, then the owner has full copyright over that block of code. He / she cannot, in any circumstance, copyright something like

```
a:link {text-decoration: none}
```

Comment: By no means can this be considered legal advice, for I am not a legally-practising lawyer. My knowledge is procured from personal research and applies strictly to the US.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I am not looking for legal advice either. I just wanted to know the industry-wide practice. I got the answer from you thanks. I understand we get inspired and that influences our creativity. "trade dress' was very insightful.

Comment: u mean a css file with no copyright notice can be easily used like this one https://platform.twitter.com/css/tweet.f2717a85d01fdfb9746f308a329853c8.light.ltr.css

Comment: Ah, sort of. The twitter one is MIT-licensed, so that enables you to use it without concern. I'm saying that it's a bit of a legal disaster to claim copyright ownership to CSS. You can if you invoke trade dress. So it's possible, but difficult :(

Answer (score 3):

There is plenty of copying going around on the internet. It is difficult to stay away from. But to honestly answer your question it is illegal to copy someone else work, unless you get consent from the owner, but be aware that this is the unique work of the owner and not copied either.

Now a lot of work is not that unique and is pretty much the standard way of developing say javascript, so if thats the case I do not see a problem with it. But related to actually copying images, css, styles, colors, it is tricky. If the techniques are generally used and you create your own images and different colors it can be acceptable, otherwise I suggest coming up with your own. Also stay away from copying from recognized brands.

I do believe we can use other websites to our advantage and get inspired by designs, techniques,  solutions and help it to drive our own creativity.